# Best pattern for AWS Cognito / React frontend / Django Rest backend

Tags: python, django, jwt, boto, amazon-cognito

Struggling to get this fully working - here is my app workflow:

React frontend - user authenticates w/ Cognito directly (using AWS Amplify) - I've got this working fine. The frontend needs to handle this, as it makes separate direct calls to other AWS services.

DRF backend - React then makes API calls to DRF endpoints using Amplify.API, which includes the x-amz-security-token in the request header (this appears to be the Session Token returned by Amplify's call to the cognito-idp service). So now the backend has the Session Token (but not the Access Token or Refresh Token)

The backend then simply needs to verify that the frontend user (whose authenticated identity I assume is represented by the Session Token) is a valid and currently authenticated user according to Cognito. So the backend needs to make a separate call to Cognito to verify this.

This is where I'm failing - I've looked at django-warrant, but I can't discern from the documentation whether this is appropriate for my use case (or even how to really use it - the default setup suggested results in various boto3 errors to do w/ lack of credentials, etc.). I've also looked at warrant and directly at boto3 and botocore but it is not clear to me where to make all this happen. Am I missing seeing some kind of is_user_valid and is_session_token_valid methods in these libraries?

If someone knows how to do this directly w/ django-warrant it would help, and if not a little advice on the best way forward would also be appreciated (do I write my own authentication backed or middleware to intercept the request, authenticate somehow w/ boto3 or botocore, or what?)

Many thanks

Comment: So I have almost sorted this out myself - a number of my assumptions and understandings of the process were incorrect - when complete I will post in detail

Comment: I am working on a similar setup (Cognito + React + Django DRF). I have got the cognito working as well and receive id, session and access token. I was thinking I have to pass the access token as authorization token to DRF but not sure how to decode it in drf. Can u post ur implementation so i can use it as reference. Many Thanks.

Comment: @user96675 I'm setting up a github React/Cognito/DRF boilerplate app will advise when I upload

Comment: thats awesome .. waiting eagerly to hear back from you ... thanks a lot.

Comment: @user96675 just a hint in the meantime - first use the API.* method from Amplify to make your api calls to DRF, you can set it up to include the JWT from Cognito in the headers. Then in DRF, parse out the JWT and validate against the current JWKs from Cognito (you have to make a call from Django to obtain these as well as create your own authentication middleware). That's a very macro overview but it might get you started.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will give it a try and see how i go.

Comment: @tunecrew What is your solution on this so far?

Comment: @Sarit see my comment above - I made a custom middleware in Django which determines if the JWT is valid. I'm going to write a longer post on it when I have a chance.

Comment: @tunecrew Have you managed to write the post about this setup? it's similar to what I'm struggling right now, I've tried using this https://github.com/LabD/django-cognito-jwt but can't make it work

Comment: Did anyone find an answer on this? It is currently relevant for me.